# Help needed - Browse music folders and show metadata of audio files

Tags: music, file-management, audio-player, metadata

I have just installed Elementary on a laptop and I would love to play some music...

I look for a way I can browse the existing folders where the music is saved and from there be able to see the metadata of the songs. Ultimately it would be good if I could play the songs too! ;-) can anybody help me please? :-)

Before I used Windows and I "just" had to add the attributes' columns (Artist, Album, Year, Bit rate...) in the folder view.

I have tried EasyTAG but the browsing is not very smooth as I am asked, there I experience many notifications popping out every time I open a folder. Also Picard is showing me the metadata of only one song at a time.

I look forward to hear from any of you. Cheerios L

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible by default. However you can go the long way round and do the following: Add all your music to the music library and search any song that you want using the Music app. Then right click on it and you can choose to open its location on the File Browser.

Comment: ugh, there is no way i can simply browse the existing folders? the music library is already organized in folders and so on.I also imagine that it would be necessary to repeat the step you describe every time i connect an external hard disk. Is there a file browsing app that simply allows the view of files' metadata?

Comment: Music should add automatically the music if you connect a device so you shouldn't need to do it manually. About the files app I'm not sure, will try to find something

Comment: https://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/ can you try this one? I think it may have what you want.